Swift array in firebase RTD returning invalid values between elements
I have a json that for some strange reason is returning two different values, one is an array and the rest as a dictionary which is making it difficult to parse.
Here is the relevant code that creates the JSON element
 func crtJson() -> [AnyHashable: Any] {
        
        let myDays = [
                        "1": ["Chap": ["1":"0", "2":"0", "3":"0", "4":"0"], "Comp": "0"],
                        "2": ["Chap": ["5":"0", "6": "0", "7": "0", "8": "0"], "Comp": "0"],
                        "3": ["Chap": ["9":"0", "10": "0", "11": "0", "12": "0"], "Comp": "0"],
                        "4": ["Chap": ["13":"0", "14": "0", "15": "0", "16": "0", "17": "0"], "Comp": "0"],
                        "5": ["Chap": ["18":"0", "19": "0", "20": "0"], "Comp": "0"],
                        "6": ["Chap": ["21":"0", "22": "0", "23": "0"], "Comp": "0"],
                        "7": ["Chap": ["24":"0", "25": "0"], "Comp": "0"],
                        "8": ["Chap": ["26":"0", "27": "0", "28": "0"], "Comp": "0"],
                        "9": ["Chap": ["29":"0", "30": "0", "31": "0"], "Comp": "0"]
                     ]
        print(myDays)
        let jsonObject: [String: Any] = [
            "Days": myDays
        ]


        let valid = JSONSerialization.isValidJSONObject(jsonObject) // true
        print(jsonObject)
            return jsonObject
    }

As you will notice, I have it coded exactly the same except for the number of CHAP elements which should not have any impact.
When I attempt to read this with the following code
func validateBook(mDay: Int) {
    var intArray = [Any]()
    let ref = Database.database()
    let firUser = Auth.auth().currentUser
    let myPath = "users/\(firUser!.uid)/Yrly/Days/\(mDay)/Chap"
    let myRef1 = ref.reference().child(myPath)
    print(myRef1.url)
    myRef1.observe(.value, with: {
        snapshot in
        print(snapshot.value)
        let myArray = snapshot.value as! NSArray
        for n in 1...(myArray.count - 1)  {
            if (myArray[n] as! String) != "3" {
                self.retVal = false
            }
        }
        if self.retVal == true {
            // Update day to completed
            print("Day completed")
            let ref = Database.database().reference()
            let pathString = self.firuser! + "/Yrly/Days/\(String(mDay))/"
            print(pathString)
            let post = ["Comp": "3"]
            ref.child("users").child(pathString).updateChildValues(post)
        }
    })
}

I get the following value for the FIRST element: (What I mean by first element is DAY 1)
Optional(<__NSArrayM 0x600000db4300>(
<null>, 
3,
0,
0,
0
)
)

For all the other elements :
Optional({
5 = 3;
6 = 0;
7 = 0;
8 = 0;
})
Could not cast value of type '__NSDictionaryM' (0x1f1d06c88) to 'NSArray' (0x1f1d02048).

So why is it reading day 1 as an array but everything else as a dictionary?
I tried changing the following line to a dictionary:
let myArray = snapshot.value as! NSArray

to the following:
let myArray = snapshot.value as! NSDictionary
it blows up as well.  For some reason it always makes the first element an array and everything else a dictionary.

What did you print exactlty? Which line causes the crash? That's strange because in crtJson, I see only Dictionaries, no Arrays...

myRef1.observe(.value, with: {
snapshot in
print(snapshot.value)
let myArray = snapshot.value as! NSArray
for n in 1...(myArray.count - 1)  {
if (myArray[n] as! String) != "3" {
self.retVal = false
}
} in the validate section the let myArray is blowing up

for some reason in the crtjson it is writing the data with a NULL, even though it is clearly not.

Using sequential numeric indexes as keys in your Firebase Realtime Database structure is an anti-pattern, precisely because of the behavior you're encountering.

Firebase Realtime Database stores arrays as key/value pairs with numerical keys. So when you have an array:
["first", "second", "third"]

Firebase actually stores that as:
{
  "0": "first",
  "1": "second",
  "2": "third"
}

Then when a client (either REST API or SDK) reads this data, it detects the pattern of sequential keys and converts it back to an array.
Firebase sees no difference between these two data snippets: an array is simply treated as a map with numeric sequential keys, and thus vice versa: a map with numeric sequential keys is treated as an array.
This works great when you have an actual array, but breaks down when you get a subset of the data (with a query) - or when you have a non-array object where you just happen to use (almost) sequential numbers as keys. Depending on the exact results, the SDK may fill in missing entries in the array (the <null> in your first result or not perform array coercion altogether.

The solution is to follow best practices and to not use array indexes as keys in Firebase Realtime Database. A simple workaround I often use is to prefix the keys with a short alphanumeric value.
{
  "key_0": "first",
  "key_1": "second",
  "key_2": "third"
}

Also see Best Practices: Arrays in Firebase (which is over a decade old by now ).
